# Hide "href" URL in modal

Tags: html

I have a problem, I can not solve.
Basically I want to hide the URL "href"

this here:
[image]

I have a modal I did, however when I click to perform the url # appears

Example modal:
https://jsfiddle.net/cp1xow5s/1/

the url comes from this code:

" #close " /

```
<a href="#close" title="Fechar" class="close">X</a>
```

OBS:
1- I tried that and it didn't work

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: "";
  }
}
```

I may have done something wrong, since I am beginner in this area ;)

Comment: is it a real website ??? or just a html file ??? if you are on a real site and server you can edit url using **.htaccess** file easily .     in that example you attached , if check the button url you see **https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/#video** it's a different url of current page **https://jsfiddle.net** . that is a shell

Comment: yes it is a real website, I was wondering if i could solve the code base, but from what I see I'll have to stick with the ".htaccess", thank you for your attention ..